# Why doesn't particle-antiparticle annihilation violate conservation of energy? If the particles appeared from the vacuum, and leave behind gamma rays?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, energy, particle-physics, quantum-electrodynamics

I noticed a 'Similar Question' above, when posting this, but I am interested in the conservation of energy part....

I know I was taught (and have repeatedly read) that virtual particles aren't actually foaming up, so to speak, out in the middle of nowhere, but only near concentrations of other energies (I.e. matter, usually). .....

Still, if a pair does truly, physically, appear and annihilate, with each other or something else, how does the resulting EM energy blast not violate conservation of energy?

P.S.: What about the Casimir Effect?  Has that been proven, to the extent that such things can be proven?  Where does the energy then go?  Does it just disappear again?

Comment: What do you mean by "physically"? Feynman diagrams are terms in a perturbation series. Moreover, the vacuum correction diagrams of the kind you're describing simply arise because we start with a free theory vacuum and add corrections to its normalization perturbatively. So whenever you calculate any correlation function (not even the S-matrix), these get cancelled out with the same correction factors of normalization that arise in states created by acting on the vacuum.

Comment: Another way to put it: we know from basic principles that vacuum to vacuum amplitude (without any insertions) should be 1, because the vacuum is an energy eigenstate, i.e., a stationary state. So, in physical reality, if you take a vacuum state of a QFT and evolve it in time, literally nothing happens. But, if we start from the free theory vacuum and calculate the true vacuum to true vacuum amplitudes perturbatively, then we get a Feynman series of the vacuum diagrams of the kind you describe. But, as I explained, from QM first principles, we know that nothing is actually happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said it yourself ", but only near concentrations of other energies ". If particles with real four vectors appear , the energy has been taken either from an incoming particle or from some field.

See the pair creation [crossection,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_production#Cross_section) which is connected with the probability of observation of the pair, in the diagram below , from the energy of the incoming gamma:

[image: pairprod]

> Feynman diagram of electron–positron pair production. One must calculate multiple diagrams to get the net cross section

The nucleus above and the virtual gamma are necessary for conservation laws as a photon has zero mass and cannot just decay to two massive particles.

Comment: What about the Casimir effect?  Some things I read say it isn't real, but... Would Casimir happen even in a very isolated place?

Comment: The Casimir effect when interpreted with QFT involves virtual particles between plates of material, so not isolated.